# What is the difference between ACL and user roles in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to symfony2 and i am confused with the terms and what is use case for these.
can anyone please explain what is the difference between

1. ACL
2. Roles
3. Groups

Comment: As I were looking for the same thing and I were deciding if use voters or ACE, here I found some slides that explains well all the concepts: http://slides.com/marieminasyan/drop-ace-use-role-voters#/

Answer (score 38):

Let's take the most basic example: a Blog application (again).

When building a blog application, you often need to authenticate users and authorize them to do specific actions, like:

- authorize Bob to add a new contributor to the blog
- authorize Alice to create a new blog post
- authorize Alice to edit her own blog post
- authorize Bob to delete Alice's blog post

### What is a Role

A role represents **a set of permissions, hard coded in your application**.
When checking if a user is allowed to add a new contributor to the blog, your code checks if the current user has the Role "ROLE_ADMIN".

That's why Bob (he has the ROLE_ADMIN) is allowed to add a Alice as a new Contributor.
See [Symfony documentation on Security/Roles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles).

### What is a Group

When a user belongs to a group, she's usually **entitled a set of Roles**.
Alice belongs to the group "Contributors", so she has the Roles ROLE_STATS (she's allowed to see the blog stats) and ROLE_POST (she's allowed to post a new blog entry).

Again, this concept is not hard coded in Symfony, but developers usually think it that way.
See [some bit on managing Roles in a database with Groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database).

### ACLs

Access Control Lists come in handy when you need to take a authorization decision based **on a Role + a domain object**.

Alice is allowed to edit blog entries written by her only. To check this authorization, you need Alice's Roles and the Post model she's trying to edit.
[Symfony's documentation on ACLs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) is also pretty clear about that.

Oh, and Bob is allowed to edit all blog entries because he has the ROLE_ADMIN. The decision here is only based on a Role.